# extract data from clob column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having data in clob column as below:

```
:1A:CAD22021828,17
:1B:RECEIVE GENERAL IND
11 BEGUM ST 3-15A2
  VILL              AP IND 313 416
:1C:/000061071257      CC
RECEIVER GENERAL FOR IND
C/O PNBB MAIN BRANCH
11 BEGUM ST 3-15A2
AA HYD         APIND
```

Now my requirement is to load this into 3 separate columns in target table as below:

```
1A    - CAD22021828,17
1B    - RECEIVE GENERAL IND 
        11 BEGUM ST 3-15A2
        VILL              AP IND 313 416
1C    - /000061071257      CC
        RECEIVER GENERAL FOR IND
        C/O PNBB MAIN BRANCH
        11 BEGUM ST 3-15A2
        AA HYD         APIND
```

can someone suggest how I can do this.

This is oracle 11.2

I have tried below code ;

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(mc_clob,':1A:([[:alnum:]]+\S+)') AS code1A,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(mc_clob,':1B:([[:alnum:]]+\s+)') AS code1B,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(mc_clob,':1C:([[:alnum:]]+\s+)') AS code1c
FROM tableA;
```

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with capture groups:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(mc_clob, ':1A:(.*):1B:', 1, 1, 'n', 1) AS code1A,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(mc_clob,':1B:(.*):1C:', 1, 1, 'n', 1) AS code1B,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(mc_clob,':1C:(.*)', 1, 1, 'n', 1) AS code1c
FROM tableA;
```

[image: Screen capture of result set from demo]

### Demo

To understand how this works, take the first call to `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(mc_clob, ':1A:(.*):1B:', 1, 1, 'n', 1)
```

This says to match `:1A:(.*):1B:`, capturing all content between the `:1A:` and `:1B:` markers.  The fifth parameter is `n`, which tells Oracle to let dot match across newlines.  That is, `(.*)` will capture all content between the two markers, including across lines.  The sixth parameter is `1`, which means that the return value will be the first (and only) capture group.  Similar logic applies to the second and third call to `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However the columns might not be same for all the rows. I mean some times the data will be 1A 2A 3B or 1A 1B 1C like that. I need to retrieve data that in between colons :1A:  and the next : like that

Comment: Then you should edit your question and show better sample data.

Comment: First row : 1A:CAD22021828,17
:1B:RECEIVE GENERAL IND
11 BEGUM ST 3-15A2
  VILL              AP IND 313 416
:1C:/000061071257      CC
RECEIVER GENERAL FOR IND
C/O PNBB MAIN BRANCH
11 BEGUM ST 3-15A2
AA HYD         APIND

Comment: First row in table:
1A:CAD22021828,17
:1B:RECEIVE GENERAL IND
11 BEGUM ST
:1C:     
C/O PNBB MAIN BRANCH
11 BEGUM ST 3-15A2
:

Second row in table:
:1A:/002429389016
CITY OF NAGAL AP IN 392H 329
:1E://NAGOLE STREET
NAGAL AP
:2A:/154510002
OFD DEPOSITORY LTD
:

Now i want this data to be loaded in another table as below: 
1st row: 
1A CAD22021828,17  
1B RECEIVE GENERAL IND 11 BEGUM ST /000061071257
1C C/O PNBB MAIN BRANCH 11 BEGUM ST 3-15A2
2nd row:
1A /002429389016 CITY OF NAGAL AP IN 392H 329
1E //NAGOLE STREET NAGAL AO
2A /154510002 OFD DEPOSITORY LTD